# Openedge record scope using for each and first-of

Tags: scope, transactions, openedge

I have a bit of a puzzling problem that I have never encountered before. Running in a production environment this seems to be fine but in a standalone procedure editor or mpro session it is failing so I would like to understand why..

```
FOR EACH employee NO-LOCK BREAK BY employee.company:
    IF FIRST-OF(employee.company) THEN 
    DO:
        FIND company WHERE company.company = employee.company NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
    END.

    MESSAGE FIRST-OF(employee.company) SKIP
            AVAILABLE company
         VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX. 
END.
```

I was expecting that providing the company record exists, for each employee record of that company I would see that the company record is available, this is not the case, once we hit the second occurrence of the company it is no longer available.

I can get it to work using strong scoping as seen below but I would like to know whether or not there is some kind of start up parameter or something that I am missing as, as stated above this works fine in a production environment in its program. I should add that the code in the production environment lives in a procedure in a standard .p.

```
DO FOR employee, company:
    FOR EACH employee NO-LOCK BREAK BY employee.company:
        IF FIRST-OF(employee.company) THEN 
        DO:
            FIND company WHERE company.company = employee.company NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
        END.

        MESSAGE FIRST-OF(employee.company) SKIP
                AVAILABLE company
            VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX. 
    END.
END.
```

Answer (score 1):

Your production code likely has a reference to COMPANY somewhere outside the FOR EACH.

To test that idea, instead of the strong-scoping block add something like:

```
FIND COMPANY where COMPANY.something = ? NO-LOCK NO-ERROR.
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, that test does seem to do the trick. I can that the table is indeed referenced outside of the for each but in other internal procedures. None of them use a buffer so wondering if it's something to do with that or as nwahmaet says below, a strange procedure buffer thing as his suggestion does also produce the result I expect.

Comment: You might try compiling with LISTING to see what buffers are scoped where.

Answer (score 1):

There's also potentially something strange relating to the procedure buffer scope.

If you put the for each into an internal procedure, and run the internal procedure, things work as you expect them to. Run in the main block of a .p, and the (department, in my case) record goes out of scope on the next iteration.

Take a look at https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=657895e120add51d93a67a9d

Comment: Thanks, this does produce what I expected in the first instance so it must be something to do with this, would just be nice to be able to read something somewhere that was definitive :D

Comment: If you compile with the LISTING option you will see that all of your buffers are scoped to the main procedure. Not to the internal procedure or the FOR block. If you remove the internal procedure they get scoped to the FOR block rather than the main procedure. I think believe this is because the internal procedure is "borrowing" the undeclared buffers from the containing (main) procedure. If you add "define buffer X for X." statements to the internal procedure the buffers will then be scoped to the FOR.